# Facebook Publish Error In Android Application

Tags: android

HI Friends,

I implemented facebook connect in android using facebook-android-sdk. Most of the times I am getting error while i am publishing.

Less number of times publish is working fine.

Publish story window is opening good with What's on your mind text box. When i am clicking on the publish button in the Publish story window, i am getting error.

The error is  constantly changing when i coming(clicking ) to next time.

some of the the  errors i have been seen in my application when i am clicking in the publish button are.

**Error Examples:**
1. `An error occurred with Holyplanets Connect.please try again later`

1. `An error occurred with WordpressBlog Connect.please try again later`
2. `An Error occurred with UFOS ON EARTH. Please try agian later`

How can i fix this error? If anybody knows please let me know.

Thanks and Regards,

Kiran

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a fault with Facebook.com.

I started getting this yesterday in my iOS app which has been out for months.